# How can I highlight an element in Inter Explorer browser by using xpath(Like we have this option in Google chrome)

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[click on link for attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR7qh.png)

I am new to selenium, I want to know how we can highlight a WebElement in Internet explorer browser. I am using IE 11 version.

Example: I have a web-page, over there I have an element, I have written xapth for that element, but can I verify it on IE browser, to be double sure that my written xpath is unique.

Edit: I have added image, I have verified an element in xpath in Google Chrome browser, This is what I want to achieve in Inter Explorer browser.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify if your selector is unique or not you can simply try to get list of elements and assert its length.

*Python code*

```
assert len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your_xpath")) == 1
```

If length of list returns you more than `1` - your selector is not unique

If you want to *highlight* element matched by your selector:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.background = 'rgb(138,43,226 )';", element)
```

P.S. This is not the same as in Chrome... Reload page to drop new background color

Comment: Thank you for your update @Andersson, but can you please click on image link, This is what I want in Internet explorer driver.

Comment: Awesome answer, covers both the usecases(+1)

Comment: @MamtaGupta , AFAIK IE has no such features and I have no possibility to implement such features

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply check ONCE that you have the correct xpath and have the possibility to install a different browser, I would recommend simply using Chrome.

In Chrome, you can open the developer tools (F12) > Elements > Ctrl + F. You can then search for xpath or css selector and it will show you the amount of results and also highlight the selected result in the HTML. If you hover over it it will highlight the element on the rendered page.

The xpath is independent of a browser, so even if the goal is to test something in IE, you can still use a different browser to assist in writing your tests.

Comment: The xpath is really browser independent, but DOM might differs in different browsers